# How to call unsafe code from ASP.NET xproj

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, asp.net-core, unsafe

I created a class library today with the new `Class Library (Package)` templates in Visual Studio 2015. Apparently it uses a fancy new project format, the ASP.NET xproj, for building the package. While that's fine by me, how do I call unsafe code from the library? I looked into **Project > Properties > Build**, where the option to toggle unsafe code should be, but all I got was this:

[image]

So yeah, no such luck. I even tried pasting `"<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>"` manually into the .xproj file, but the compiler still complains.

Is it possible to enable this without creating another non-xproj assembly for the unsafe methods?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The ASP.NET 5 tools are not documented nearly well enough, but after scouring Google for half an hour I came across the solution.

In your project.json file, add this line:

```
{
    "buildOptions": { "allowUnsafe": true }
}
```

[Source.](http://forums.asp.net/t/2012315.aspx?Using+kpm+build+to+package+a+project+that+contains+unsafe+code+)

Comment: DNX uses it in their own codebase too. [`Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime`](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime/project.json) for example.

Comment: Extended documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json