# Unsafe code compilation error in .NET Core even after setting allowunsafe flag to true in project.json

Tags: .net, .net-core, unsafe, coreclr

I am using some unsafe code in my .NET Core app.
For that, I had made this change in the **project.json** file:

```json
"compilationOptions": {
    "allowUnsafe": true,
}
```

However, I still get the error `CS0227: Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe`.

I had already gone through this:

- [Unsafe code won't compile on Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295228/unsafe-code-wont-compile-on-visual-studio-2015)
- [How to call unsafe code from ASP.NET xproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211739/how-to-call-unsafe-code-from-asp-net-xproj)

Comment: Try using "buildOptions" instead of "compilationOptions". The latter was renamed at some point, and you should get some sort of deprecation warning about it, although that may have been removed at some point.

Comment: @EricMellino, you should make this an answer Get the credit!
Also, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**NOTE:

This answer is based on earlier *.Net Core/Standard* project formats written in `json`. For the new formatted `csproj` [see Ray's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46498238/210709).**

Change `compilationOptions` to `buildOptions`:

```json
"buildOptions": {
    "allowUnsafe": true
}
```

Answer (score 67):

In the newer `*.csproj` files, this is now:

```
<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
```

in any `PropertyGroup`.