# Allow unsafe code in jetbrains rider?

Tags: c#, unsafe, rider

I need to write an `unsafe` method in C# and apparently "unsafe construct cannot be used in safe context". I went to project properties and saw a switch to allow unsafe code in Debug and Release builds.

However, it is not clickable.

[image]

How do I allow unsafe code for my project?

Edit: adding `<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>` to `PropertyGroup` tag in the `csproj` file does fix the problem but I was wondering if there is a way to do this in the IDE itself, since I expect IDEs to be able to do these sort of stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsafe Code Compilation error in .Net Core even after setting allowunsafe flag to true in project.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256383/unsafe-code-compilation-error-in-net-core-even-after-setting-allowunsafe-flag-t)

Comment: I think it is a bug in a Rider =)

Comment: Would you mind opening a feature request for this one at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER#newIssue ?

Answer (score 4):

use Alt-Enter on the "unsafe" keyword in your code. There you will find the option to "allow unsafe code for ethis project".

I would not know how to undo thst later though. Funny that the Rider manual does not say anything about that.